# Searching two model from single search form in Yii

Tags: php, yii

```
property with field
{
    id,
    ttile,
    ....
    .......

    and inspectiontime with field 
    id,
    time,
    property_id
```

and in property model i have relation

```
   'instime'=>array(self::HAS_MANY,'Inspection','property_id'), 

}
```

So my objective is to search property which will have inspection time( there may be the case of property not having inspection time and each property may have multiple inspection time as relation in model says) and i can also able to search the property through the inspection time.

Thank you and appreciating for help in this matter.

Answer (score 0):

In your model, update search function.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->with = array( 'instime' );
...
$criteria->compare( 'instime.inspection_time', $this->inspection_time, true );
...
```

You have to declare inspection_time as class variable in  property model

Comment: with this i am getting all the property which will not have inspection time too, but i want only those property which have inspection time